# Условие OR в .str.contains

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки, pandas, dataframe

**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**

```
import pandas as pd

(df
 .query(qry).loc[lambda x: x["название"].str.contains(r"rtx", case=False)].sort_values('цена', ascending=False)
```

Как правильно прописать, чтобы поиск шёл по вхождению: **rtx** или **palit** или **msi** и т.д., а не только по **rtx** как сейчас. Пробовал OR в разных вариантах подставить - безуспешно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
str.contains(r"rtx|palit|msi", case=False, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы проверить на вхождение одной из искомых подстрок в строку обычно используют регулярные выражения - `"substr1|substr2|substr3"`. Но в вашем случае безопаснее будет убедиться, что подстроки по совпадению не являются частью другого слова:

```
srch_strings = ["rtx", "palit", "msi"]
srch_pat = "|".join(rf"\b{s}\b"for s in srch_strings) 

df.query(qry).loc[lambda x: x["название"].str.contains(srch_pat, case=False)]
```

---

получившееся регулярное выражение будет искать только такие вхождения, где искомое слово отделено границами слова (`"\b"`). Т.е. в строках "princi**palit**ies" и "clu**msi**ness" вхождения найдены не будут.

---

Пример:

```
In [66]: df
Out[66]:
             название
0  a palit video card
1      principalities
2          clumsiness
3                 msi

In [67]: print(srch_pat)
\brtx\b|\bpalit\b|\bmsi\b

In [68]: df.loc[lambda x: x["название"].str.contains(srch_pat, case=False)]
Out[68]:
             название
0  a palit video card
3                 msi
```